# The system cannot find the file specified,Insight.Database micro orm

Tags: insight.database

I was playing around with the new Insight.Databse micro ORM to get my hands dirty.When I try to insert an object into the databe ,by using the extension method on the ConnectionStringSettings ,it throws he above error.I have the table and stored procedures created in the databse as per the documentation.This is the piece that throws the exception(Where I call the InsertCustomer on the repo)

public class CustomerRepository
    {
        public static async Task InsertCustomer(Customer cust)
        {
            var connection = ConfigSettings.ConnectionString;
            var repo =  connection.As();
           return await repo.InsertCustomer(cust);
        }
    }

public interface ICustomerRepository
    {
        Task InsertCustomer(Customer cust);
    }

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks
RJ

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a NotImplementedException, and running v4.1.0 to 4.1.3 you're probably running into a problem registering your database provider.

I recommend using v4.1.4 or later and making sure you register the provider for your database.

See

https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database/wiki/Installing-Insight

If you have any more problems, you can post an issue on github.